# Is there a Biurei Zohar online of the Mittler Rebbe

Tags: torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism, chabad, zohar

Does anyone know if there is a Biurei Zohar Copy online of the Mittler Rebbe?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a PDF version on HebrewBooks: https://hebrewbooks.org/20661